# на экране появилось окошо с надписью ESET online scanner , ни на что не реагирует, только можно передвигать по экрану

Tags: windows

на экране появилось окошо с надписью  ESET online scanner , ни на что не реагирует, только можно передвигать по экрану

Comment: Какая реакция на комбинации ctrl+alt+del, crtl+shift+esc, alt+tab, shift+F10, win+ctrl+"o"

Comment: Антивирус ESET установлен на компьютере?

Comment: Safe mode -> System Restore, или  PE Boot -> System Restore, или удаление вручную Safe mode -> Registry Editor удаление сервисов антивируса